# Windows 8.1 IE11(Edge) Google map JavaScript API v3 Pinch zoom in/out Issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-11

Google map javascript v3 pinching zoom in and out is not working on IE11(Edge) win8.1 preview OS after updating my OS from windows 8 to windows 8.1 preview. Please see my screenshot here:

[image]

This is all working fine with my previews windows 8 and IE10. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

If pinch to zoom doesn't work on [official examples](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple), then this sounds like a bug.

File a bug report for this behavior at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?q=apitype:Javascript3

Comment: You might want to upvote the existing bug report for this: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5747